# login form codeigniter form validation show one more login form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have below code for login form with validation,

```
 public function index(){
            //Check weather session exist or not!
            if(($this->session->userdata('user_email') != ""))
                {
                    if(($this->session->userdata('is_admin') == "Yes"))
                        {
                        redirect('admin/home'); 
                        }
                        elseif(($this->session->userdata('is_manager') == "Yes"))
                        {
                            redirect('manager/home');   
                            }
                    else
                        {
                            redirect('user/home');  
                        }
                }
            else
                {
                $this->load->view('view_login');
                }

    //If not exists then get login post request
    if ($this->input->post('login')) 
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('view_login');
            } 
            else {

                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
                $user_count = $this->login_model->user_count($username,$password);  

                if($user_count == 1)
                        {
                            // If there is a user, then check enable status
                            $row = $this->login_model->user_data($username,$password);

                                if($row->user_status == "Enable")
                                    {
                                        $_userdata = array(
                                            'user_id' => $row->user_id,
                                            'user_email' => $row->user_email,
                                            'user_firstname' => $row->user_firstname,
                                            'user_lastname' => $row->user_lastname,
                                            'user_image' =>$row->user_image,
                                            'is_admin' => $row->is_admin,
                                            'is_manager' => $row->is_manager,
                                            'user_tz' =>$row->tz_name,
                                            'logged_in' => true
                                            );

                                        $this->session->set_userdata($_userdata);
                                        //Now check user type weather admin or user then move to respected page
                                            if($row->is_admin == "Yes")
                                                {
                                                redirect('admin/home');
                                                }
                                                elseif($row->is_manager == "Yes")
                                                {
                                                    redirect('manager/home');
                                                    }
                                            else 
                                                {
                                                redirect('user/home');
                                                }   


                                    }
                                    else
                                            {
                                                $error = array(
                                                            'error_message' => 'User Name is Disabled'
                                                            );
                                                $this->load->view('view_login', $error); // Manager Disables

                                            }
                        }
                    else
                        {
                                    $data1 = array(
                                            'error_message' => 'Wrong Username or Password'
                                                );
                                    $this->load->view('view_login', $data1); //Wrong user pw
                        }

                }
        }
}
```

What i am doing here is when index is load, check weather any session exist or not, and if yes, then simply redirect to home page of user,
If no session exists then load login view page,

Then user enter username and PW then form validation is done,
And if it fails, the loading view page again, this page will show error of CI form validation,

Problem is, when validation fails, i get two login forms on view, means one was already which used for login and another login form with CI validation errors,

How can i get only 1 login form when CI send validation error?
My guess is that i am loading view_login page 2 times, but not sure how can i prevent that!

Thanks,

Comment: Show me your full code.

Comment: Updated code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this and let me know.   
 <?php
     function index(){
                //Check weather session exist or not!
                if(($this->session->userdata('user_email') != ""))
                    {
                        if(($this->session->userdata('is_admin') == "Yes"))
                            {
                            redirect('admin/home'); 
                            }
                            elseif(($this->session->userdata('is_manager') == "Yes"))
                            {
                                redirect('manager/home');   
                                }
                        else
                            {
                                redirect('user/home');  
                            }
                    }


        //If not exists then get login post request
        else if ($this->input->post('login')) 
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'User Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('view_login');
                } 
                else {

                    $username = $this->input->post('username');
                    $password = md5($this->input->post('password'));
                    $user_count = $this->login_model->user_count($username,$password);  

                    if($user_count == 1)
                            {
                                // If there is a user, then check enable status
                                $row = $this->login_model->user_data($username,$password);

                                    if($row->user_status == "Enable")
                                        {
                                            $_userdata = array(
                                                'user_id' => $row->user_id,
                                                'user_email' => $row->user_email,
                                                'user_firstname' => $row->user_firstname,
                                                'user_lastname' => $row->user_lastname,
                                                'user_image' =>$row->user_image,
                                                'is_admin' => $row->is_admin,
                                                'is_manager' => $row->is_manager,
                                                'user_tz' =>$row->tz_name,
                                                'logged_in' => true
                                                );

                                            $this->session->set_userdata($_userdata);
                                            //Now check user type weather admin or user then move to respected page
                                                if($row->is_admin == "Yes")
                                                    {
                                                    redirect('admin/home');
                                                    }
                                                    elseif($row->is_manager == "Yes")
                                                    {
                                                        redirect('manager/home');
                                                        }
                                                else 
                                                    {
                                                    redirect('user/home');
                                                    }   


                                        }
                                        else
                                                {
                                                    $error = array(
                                                                'error_message' => 'User Name is Disabled'
                                                                );
                                                    $this->load->view('view_login', $error); // Manager Disables

                                                }
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                        $data1 = array(
                                                'error_message' => 'Wrong Username or Password'
                                                    );
                                        $this->load->view('view_login', $data1); //Wrong user pw
                            }

                    }
            } else
                    {
                    $this->load->view('view_login');
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Worked as i expected :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the load view_login statement from the else part and put as else for the $this->input->post('login') as shown below:

```
    if ($this->input->post('login')) 
    {
          ........ 
          ........
    } else {
          $this->load->view('view_login');
    }
```

Comment: If i remove view_login from else part then controller will not load my view_login and i will have blank page,

Comment: Anyway at last that view is loading rt?

Comment: Yes, it will load but again i have two forms with both have errors from CI validations